# First Report after recycling (12 hrs by default) is taking very long to generate in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, recycle

We have a report hosted on one of our SSRS Server, which gets called from our web application when user clicks on generate report. Most of the time it is very fast (1- 2 secs), however when SSRS server recycles once in 12 hrs (default), first report after that recycle is taking very very long time (more than 20 sec).

And apart from this recycling thing we also felt that there is some slowness in report generation if we leave it idle for sometime. So we tried to address this issue by pinging the home page of SSRS server in every one hour. By doing this it helped us bringing the time to the range 13 - 15 sec. And then we pinged the report page directly which brought down the range to 6 - 8 sec.

So I have 2 questions here:

1.What is the ideal way of solving the slowness after recycling.

2.And does SSRS really sleep if there is any inactivity for certain period? If yes, what is the best solution for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the best solution, but at least a workaround. Set up a subscription for one of the SSRS reports so that it runs right after the scheduled recycle. You can select NULL delivery provider so it's not trying to do anything with the report, just run it. This does actually go through the motions of running the report and should get things going.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the SSRS data is being flushed from RAM.  If you have multiple SQL Server instances on the SSRS server, make sure you've appropriately set the memory limits so they are not flushing your SSRS instance data when it is less active.  Best option would be to increase the total amount of RAM on the server hosting SSRS.